# Python, writing an XML file - 'charmap' codec can't encode character. When including encoding to fix, get must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I have a program that is creating an XML file and writing it to the system.
My issues occurs when I encounter characters like '\u1d52', the system throws the error.
"charmap' codec can't encode character."

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("Cool_Output.xml", 'w'), encoding='unicode')
```

Most of the solutions online seem to suggest that simply adding some encoding will fix the issue, however when I try to add encoding I instead get the following error message:
"write() argument must be str, not bytes"

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("Cool_Output.xml", 'w', encoding="utf-8"))
```

I'm experienced in javascript and C#, but fairly new to python.
Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: Try `tree.write("Cool_Output.xml", encoding='iso-8859-1')`

Comment: @CodeMonkey That seems to work perfectly!
Why did that work, is it because XML has to be encoded in a special way?
And just a second question, why does your line not need the 'w' character, is it just using a default?

Thanks again!

Comment: With Python3 this should raise an error with "w" argument: TypeError: write() got multiple values for argument 'encoding'.

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand! I will accept that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\u1d52 is a latin small letter 'o' character probably cut-paste from Windows and iso-8859-1 encoding should work.

Try:

```python
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("Cool_Output.xml", encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

The [ElementTree.write()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) function uses the following parameters:

```
*file_or_filename* -- file name or a file object opened for writing

*encoding* -- the output encoding (default: US-ASCII)

*xml_declaration* -- bool indicating if an XML declaration should be
                     added to the output. If None, an XML declaration
                     is added if encoding IS NOT either of:
                     US-ASCII, UTF-8, or Unicode

*default_namespace* -- sets the default XML namespace (for "xmlns")

*method* -- either "xml" (default), "html, "text", or "c14n"

*short_empty_elements* -- controls the formatting of elements
                          that contain no content. If True (default)
                          they are emitted as a single self-closed
                          tag, otherwise they are emitted as a pair
                          of start/end tags
```